# Box-stacking problem in C++

Tags: c++, stl, dynamic-programming

I have tried to write code of Box stacking problem (mentioned [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/bdean/6.046/dp/)) in C++ .
Kindly give me some views on what mistakes I might have made and how I can improve.
It is running for the two inputs I have provided.

```
//============================================================================
// Name        : Boxstacking.cpp
// Author      : 
// Version     :
// Copyright   : Your copyright notice
// Description : Hello World in C, Ansi-style
//============================================================================

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
class dimension;
typedef shared_ptr<vector<dimension*> > PVecDim;
typedef vector<dimension*> VecDim;
typedef vector<dimension*>::iterator VecDimIter;
typedef shared_ptr<vector<int> > PVecInt;
typedef vector<int> VecInt;
typedef vector<int>::iterator VecIntIter;
typedef shared_ptr<vector<dimension> >  PDim;
typedef vector<dimension> Dim;
typedef vector<dimension>::iterator DimIter;

struct dimension {
    int height, width, length;
    dimension(int h, int w, int l) : height(h), width(w), length(l) {

    }
    dimension() : dimension(0,0,0) {

    }
};

class BaseComparator {
public:
    bool operator() (const dimension& a, const dimension& b) {
        if(a.width*a.length > b.width*b.length)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
};

class BoxStacking {
public:
    int doBoxStacking(PVecDim inList) {

        int i,j;

        VecDimIter it;
                cout<<"Input List"<<endl;
        for (it = inList->begin(); it != inList->end(); ++it) {
            cout<<(*it)->height<<" "<<(*it)->length<<" "<<(*it)->width<<endl;
        }

        PDim modList = getModList(inList);
        sort(modList->begin(), modList->end(), compare) ;
        cout<<"Sorted List" <<endl;

        DimIter dit;
        for(dit=modList->begin();dit!=modList->end();++dit) {
            cout<<(*dit).height<<" "<<(*dit).length<<" "<<(*dit).width<<" "<<endl;
        }

        M->reserve(modList->size());
        M->resize(modList->size());
        vector<int> prev(modList->size(), -1);

        (*M)[0] = (*modList)[0].height;

        for(i=1;i<modList->size();++i) {
            (*M)[i] = (*modList)[i].height;
            int max = (*M)[i];
            for(j=i-1;j>=0;--j) {

                if((((*modList)[i].length < (*modList)[j].length) &&
                        (*modList)[i].width < (*modList)[j].width) ||
                        (((*modList)[i].length < (*modList)[j].width) &&
                         (*modList)[i].width < (*modList)[j].length)) {
                        if(max < ((*M)[i] + (*M)[j])) {
                            max = (*M)[i] + (*M)[j];
                            prev[i] = j;
                        }
                }
            }
            (*M)[i] = max;

        }
        int ret = findMax();

        prepareOutList(modList, prev, ret);
        return (*M)[ret];
    }

    BoxStacking() : mOutList(new Dim()) , M(new VecInt()) {
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const BoxStacking& bs) {
        DimIter it;
        out<<"Output list is "<<endl;
        for(it = bs.mOutList->begin(); it!=bs.mOutList->end(); ++it) {
            out<<"{"<<(*it).height<<","<<(*it).width<<","<<(*it).length<<"}"<<endl;
        }
        return out;
    }

private:
    PDim mOutList;
    PVecInt M;
    BaseComparator compare;
    PDim getModList(PVecDim inList) {
        PDim modList(new Dim());
        VecDimIter it;
        int j=0;

        for(it = inList->begin(); it!=inList->end(); ++it) {
            dimension rot1((*it)->width, (*it)->height, (*it)->length);
            dimension rot2((*it)->length, (*it)->width, (*it)->height);

            modList->push_back(*(*it));
            modList->push_back(rot1);
            modList->push_back(rot2);

        }

        return modList;
    }

    int findMax() {
            int max=-1, pos;

            for(int i=0;i<(M)->size();i++) {
                if((*M)[i] >= max) {
                    pos = i;
                    max = (*M)[i];
                }
            }

            return pos;
        }
    void prepareOutList(PDim modList, vector<int> prev, int pos) {

        while(pos != -1) {
            mOutList->push_back((*modList)[pos]);
            pos = prev[pos];
        }
    }

};

int main(void) {
    dimension d[] = {{4, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {10, 12, 32}};
    //dimension d[] = {{1,7,9}, {6,3,5}, {10,2,4 }};
    shared_ptr<BoxStacking> bs(new BoxStacking());
    PVecDim vecdim(new VecDim());
    for (int i=0;i<sizeof(d)/sizeof(d[0]); ++i) {
        vecdim->push_back(&d[i]);
    }
    int max_height = bs->doBoxStacking(vecdim);
    cout<<"Max height is"<<max_height<<endl<<*bs;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Edit: Here's the logic I followed as well.

I'll take an example.  Suppose we have triplets `{HxWxL}={1,7,9}, {6,3,5}, {10,2,4}`.   We expand these to all possible ways we can put the boxes and also we have multiple instances of each box.  So after considering this and sorting by WxL we have `{HxWxL}={1 9 7 }{2 4 10 }{3 5 6 }{4 10 2 }{5 6 3 }{6 5 3 }{7 9 1 }{10 4 2 }{9 1 7 }`.

Now by `M[0] = h(0) = 1; M[i] = h(i) + max(M[j] | j < i`, we can put block `i` on top of block `j` using W and L).  So as we see our M vector gets created as `M[0] = 1 (from (1,9,7)`.  Next, 4x10 can't fit 9x7 in anyway so it can go to max height of 2.  Then base 5x6 can fit only on top of 9x7 n not 4x10. So we traverse the loop to find its max value and find `M[2]=3+1=4`.  Similar for others in between. We now move to 6x5x3 and see that it can fit both 4x10 (by 3x5 base) and 5x6 base among its predecessors. So we get `M[5]=max(M[2]+h[5], M[1]+h[5])`.

It turns out `M[5] = 4+6=10`. So we can go further.  We find out solution to be `{10,2,4}{6,3,5}{3,6,5}{1,7,9}` to give max 20 height.

Answer (score 6):

What quickly jumps out:

```
typedef vector<dimension*> VecDim;
        //              ^     Pointer
typedef vector<dimension*>::iterator VecDimIter;
        //              ^     Pointer
```

Its very rare to see "raw" pointers in good C++ code. This is because now you have to do memory management on the code. Pointers are useful for implementing the low down dirty bit of a structure and are used in the bowls of classes to implement higher order structures (because you can use constructor/destructor to guarantee they don't leak). But up in user space you should be using smart pointers.

But in reality I don't see any need even for smart pointers here. Just declare them as objects.

```
typedef vector<dimension> VecDim;
typedef vector<dimension>::iterator VecDimIter;
```

Now you no longer have any memory leaks (its not as if dimension is a huge object the standard copy constructor will work (and 99% of the time it will be elided)).

Also I would declare VecDemIter in terms of VecDim so that if you change the representation you only need to change it in one place and the change automatically cascades through the code.

```
typedef vector<dimension> VecDim;
typedef VecDim::iterator  VecDimIter;  // And it lines up nicer :-)
```

Now you try and use shared pointers:

```
typedef shared_ptr<vector<dimension*> > PVecDim;
                              //    ^^^   This problem should be fixed on all modern
                              //          compilers. You really don't need the space
                              //          anymore.
```

But there is no need.
The only object of this type you have has a well defined lifetime. Just use `VecDim`. Then pass the object by reference to your box algorithm.

Please consistent formatting:

```
  for (VecDimIter it = inList->begin(); it != inList->end(); ++it) {
      cout<<(*it)->height<<" "<<(*it)->length<<" "<<(*it)->width<<endl;
  }

      PDim modList = getModList(inList);
//^^^^  Why the extra indent it confused me.
```

I don't recommend calculating the size of an array:

```
for (int i=0;i<sizeof(d)/sizeof(d[0]); ++i) {
  //           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

It is really vulnerable to breakage when your code is modified later (say this part of the code is tucked into a function called `init()` and d is passed as a parameter). Personally I would define this as a vector and use the size method.

```
// This does require C++11
// But it makes it less prone to bugs.
std::vector<dimension> d = {{4, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {10, 12, 32}};
```

PPS. I prefer to name my classes (types) with an initial capitol letter (everything else starts with a lowercase letter). It makes it easy to see type names.

Lots of compilers don't like this:

```
class dimension;
struct dimension {   // struct but it was a class.
```

Neither do I. Be consistent. Since it is just a property bag make it struct in both places. Also turn on more warnings so the compiler complains about this.

Answer (score 4):

1. Your header file is wrong. This is NOT an Hello World.
2. Do not use `using namespace std` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice .
3. You can use default value for your default constructor so that you do not need two definitions : `dimension(int h = 0, int w = 0, int l = 0) : height(h), width(w), length(l){};`. As a tiny drawback, one can now provide 0, 1, 2 or 3 parameters but I am not sure it is an actual drawback.
4. The implementation of `bool operator() (const dimension& a, const dimension& b)` could just be : `return (a.width*a.length > b.width*b.length);`.
5. Do define local variable in the smallest possible scope to ease the reading. For instance, `for (VecDimIter it = inList->begin(); it != inList->end(); ++it)` ; `for (DimIter dit = modList->begin();dit!=modList->end();++dit)` ; `for (int i=1;i<modList->size();++i)` ; `for (int j=i-1;j>=0;--j)` ; etc.
6. I have the feeling that `if ((((*modList)[i].length < (*modList)[j].length) && (*modList)[i].width < (*modList)[j].width) || (((*modList)[i].length < (*modList)[j].width) && (*modList)[i].width < (*modList)[j].length))` can be simplified a bit. If I understand everything properly here, we are trying to match a box `i` in an other `j` either vertically or horizontally. In order to do so, one can just wonder whether the biggest dimension of `i` is smaller than the biggest dimension of `j` and if it is the case whether the smallest dimension of `i` is smaller than the dimension of `j`. Informally, we are just trying to match them by putting the two box in the same direction : if a horizontal box does not fit into an horizontal box, turning one will not help. (I have the feeling this must be true but I haven't proved it...). Thus, the great news is that the smallest/biggest dimension of `i` can be computed out of the loop so that whenever a new box `j` comes into play, there's less to compute.
7. This `for(i=1;i<modList->size();++i)` is not a very CPP-y way to loop over a container. If you really want to do so anyway, it's probably better to call the `size()` function only once.
8. I could do with more comments, especially regarding the different members.